# Issue overriding Primefaces5.3 css?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to override **PF 5.3** css class so i added below css class with some modification in new css file

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    color: #4F4F4F;
}
```

And I added below code inside `<h:body>` of the template

```
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="primeface_default.css" />
```

**OR**

```
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/primeface_default.css" />
```

**OR**

```
  <f:facet name="last">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/primeface_default.css" />
    </f:facet>
```

But none worked. And my page style is like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{loginBean.verifyLogged}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="../templates/home-template-new.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
    ........................
    ........................
    ........................
     </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented
>   instead. jquery.js.jsf:3255:0 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:204 Expected color but found
>   'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:2514 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:2582 Expected color but found
>   'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:3456 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:3524 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:4036 Expected
>   color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:4681 Error in parsing value for
>   'background'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:4749 Unknown
>   property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:5196
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:5315 Expected color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing
>   value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:5857
>   Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:5925 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration
>   dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:6575 Expected color but found 'top'.  Error
>   in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:6910 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:6967 Expected color but found
>   'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:7812 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:7880 Expected 'none', URL, or
>   filter function but found 'Alpha('.  Error in parsing value for
>   'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:8767 Expected 'none',
>   URL, or filter function but found 'Alpha('.  Error in parsing value
>   for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:8920 Unknown
>   property '-moz-border-radius-topleft'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:19884 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topright'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:19993 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:20106 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:20224 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topleft'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:20341 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-topright'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:20435 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:20552 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:20655 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topright'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:20775 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:20874 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topleft'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:20992 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:21088 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:21195 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:21277
>   Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'Alpha('.  Error in
>   parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:21525 Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but
>   found 'Alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration
>   dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:21757 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:21793 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:21929
>   Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:22126 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:22199 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:22285 Unknown
>   property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:22436 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration
>   dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:22551 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:22709 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:22884
>   Expected color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing value for
>   'background'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:23198 Error in
>   parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:23266 Expected color but found 'top'.  Error in
>   parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:24007 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:24075 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:24494
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:24628 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration
>   dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:24987 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:25263 Expected color but found
>   'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:25401 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:25469 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:25938
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:26125 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:26166 Expected color but found
>   'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:26307 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:26375 Expected 'none', URL, or
>   filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for
>   'filter'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:26573 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:26786
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:26984 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration
>   dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:27246 Expected color but found 'top'.  Error
>   in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:27631 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:27699 Expected ',' or '{' but
>   found 'html'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:27892 Expected ',' or '{' but found 'html'.  Ruleset
>   ignored due to bad selector. theme.css.jsf:1:27938 Expected ',' or '{'
>   but found 'html'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:27991 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:28542 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. theme.css.jsf:1:28639 Unknown
>   property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   theme.css.jsf:1:28973 Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but
>   found 'Alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration
>   dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:1:926 Expected 'none', URL, or filter
>   function but found 'mask('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'. 
>   Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:1:7288 Unknown property
>   'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:2:368 Error in
>   parsing value for 'right'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:2:621 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration
>   dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:3:32 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'. 
>   Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:3:65 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:5:1057
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:7:26 Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped
>   to next declaration. primefaces.css.jsf:7:368 Expected declaration but
>   found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. primefaces.css.jsf:7:431
>   Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-scrollbar'.  Ruleset
>   ignored due to bad selector. primefaces.css.jsf:12:1547 Unknown
>   pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-scrollbar-thumb'.  Ruleset
>   ignored due to bad selector. primefaces.css.jsf:12:1661 Unknown
>   property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:13:420
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:15:1244 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:15:1952 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:15:2789
>   Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:15:3394 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration
>   dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:15:5307 Unknown property 'zoom'. 
>   Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:15:6535 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:15:7202
>   Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:15:9100 Expected 'none', URL, or filter function
>   but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration
>   dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:16:271 Error in parsing value for
>   'display'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:17:172 Error in
>   parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:17:209 Error in parsing value for 'display'. 
>   Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:17:229 Expected declaration
>   but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:20:2738 Expected declaration but found '*'. 
>   Skipped to next declaration. primefaces.css.jsf:20:3646 Unknown
>   property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:20:4569
>   Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:20:4876 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration
>   dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:20:5773 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:25:180
>   Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:26:344 Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped
>   to next declaration. primefaces.css.jsf:26:696 Unknown property
>   'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:28:443 Unknown
>   property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:28:1187 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element
>   '-ms-clear'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
>   primefaces.css.jsf:32:635 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration
>   dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:33:44 Unknown property 'zoom'. 
>   Declaration dropped. primefaces.css.jsf:37:1103 Unknown pseudo-class
>   or pseudo-element '-webkit-scrollbar'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad
>   selector. primefaces.css.jsf:38:1832 Unknown pseudo-class or
>   pseudo-element '-webkit-scrollbar-thumb'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad
>   selector. primefaces.css.jsf:38:1946 Expected 'none', URL, or filter
>   function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'. 
>   Declaration dropped. popupPanel.ecss.jsf:11:9 Expected 'none', URL, or
>   filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for
>   'filter'.  Declaration dropped. popupPanel.ecss.jsf:21:9 Expected
>   'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing
>   value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. popupPanel.ecss.jsf:26:9
>   Error in parsing value for 'font-family'.  Skipped to next
>   declaration. style.css:11:32 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. style.css:114:12 Error in parsing value for
>   'background'.  Declaration dropped. style.css:115:12 Error in parsing
>   value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. style.css:116:12 Error
>   in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   style.css:117:12 Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found
>   'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.
>   style.css:119:8 Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found
>   'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.
>   style.css:135:33 Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found
>   'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.
>   style.css:195:35 Unknown property 'outline-size'.  Declaration
>   dropped. style.css:375:13 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. style.css:386:12 Expected end of value but found
>   'font-size'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'. 
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-common.css:95:1 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:10:22 Error
>   in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped.
>   bsm-popup.css:25:22 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'. 
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:27:22 Error in parsing value for
>   'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:28:22 Expected
>   color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:29:38 Expected 'none', URL, or
>   filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for
>   'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:30:12 Unknown property
>   '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:37:19 Unknown
>   property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped.
>   bsm-popup.css:45:22 Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration
>   dropped. bsm-popup.css:64:19 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'. 
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:68:22 Unknown property
>   '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:97:22
>   Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
>   bsm-popup.css:103:19 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:116:16 Error in parsing value for
>   'background'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:118:16 Error in
>   parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   bsm-popup.css:119:16 Expected color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing
>   value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:120:32
>   Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in
>   parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:121:12
>   Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
>   bsm-popup.css:128:16 Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:130:16 Error in parsing value for
>   'background'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:131:16 Expected
>   color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'. 
>   Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:132:32 Expected 'none', URL, or
>   filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for
>   'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bsm-popup.css:133:12 SyntaxError:
>   expected expression, got '&' dirty_check.js.jsf:1:0 Error in parsing
>   value for 'position'.  Declaration dropped. EquipmentCatalog.jsf

Comment: Please elaborate "issue" and "none worked" as if you're the developer itself, not the enduser. To start, simply view HTML page source in webbrowser how the generated HTML output look like in the place where you'd expect the `<link>` element referring the CSS file, and/or press F12 in browser and check console to verify if anything went well in client side.

Comment: @BalusC WHen i put the  `<h:outputStylesheet />` in `home-template-new.xhtml` then its showing its loaded buy css not overriding but when i put  `<h:outputStylesheet />` in my new page then css file also not loaded

Comment: You incorrectly expected that stuff outside `<ui:composition><ui:define>` would be parsed by Facelets.

Comment: @BalusC So you mean my page design is totally wrong?

Comment: You need to define template content inside `<ui:define>`, not outside. You need to put `<h:outputStylesheet>` inside `<ui:define>`, not outside. You need to learn some basic HTML too. This will help much in understanding the JSF-generated output.